# With curl, how can I pass multiple command line parameters in a POST?

Tags: curl

I have the following controller:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromQuery] int Width, [FromQuery] int Height, [FromForm] IFormFile Image)
```

With Insomnia / Postman, I can do a post command and pass the width / height parameters in the url.

I am trying to do the same with CURL but the second parameter is not seen.
In this case, height will be 0

```
curl -F image=@photo.jpg test/thumbnail?width=320&height=240
```

In that case, width will be 0

```
curl -F image=@photo.jpg test/thumbnail?height=240&width=320
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what OS/utility set are you working on? i'd start by reading the man page or equivalent for your implementation/distribution/whatever and check the `--data` or `-d` option

Comment: I'm on Mac; I tried -d "width=320" -d "height=240" but Curl told me it wasn't compatible with the multi-part post

Comment: Try them together - `-d "width=320&height=240"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely problem is that `&` is a special character in your macOS *shell* (the command-line interpreter); if left unquoted, it acts as a command separator and runs the preceding command in background. The rest (`height=240`) is interpreted as a *second* command by macOS.

So the parameter with `&` must be quoted, or the `&` itself escaped with a backslash:

```
"test/thumbnail?height=240&width=320"
test/thumbnail?height=240\&width=320
test/thumbnail?height=240"&"width=320
test/thumbnail?'height=240&width=320'
etc.
```

*(`?` is also special in that it's a wildcard, but that's only a problem if it happens to match a real filename on the local system.)*

The comments suggesting `-d` aren't correct. For one, they send parameters as POST payload – but the controller wants query-string (GET) parameters, which isn't the same thing at all. For another, the request can only use one format at a time – you cannot mix `-F` and `-d` in the same request.

Comment: works with escaping!

Answer (score 1):

for Mac OS the correct one would be

```
curl -F image=@photo.jpg test/thumbnail?width=320**\&**height=240
```

In Mac, you have to **escape `&`**